# Installing and running Silverstripe CMS on Azure

Tags: azure, silverstripe

Has anyone installed the SilverStripe CMS on Windows Azure? if so did you have any issues during the installation or with the on going running of the CMS?

On my current project I'm pushing Azure for the .Net application being developed. The application is to link with the website which has been developed using the SilverStripe CMS and I would like to have them both hosted on Azure.

Any insights/suggestions/feedback is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I can't say I have, nor do I plan to. 
But I did try SilverStripe on IIS7 (win server 2008 R2) once though, and it worked surprisingly well.

I would suggest you simply try it.
Installing just a plain fresh copy of SilverStripe is fairly simple.
Verify that you meet the [system requirements](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/installation/server-requirements) such as having mod_rewrite or an alternative, php5.3.2+ and just upload & [install](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/installation/) it.